# Copying users with copying /etc/passwd & etc/groups?

Tags: users, group

When copying users from one CentOS to another, is it enough to simply copy the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files?

Comment: Folder? Are you sure those are folders?

Comment: yes, your're right of course, files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, you also need to copy '/etc/shadow', and this will copy all the users only if the system is not configure with any external directory services such as NIS or LDAP.

To know which external services the system uses you can look in '/etc/nsswitch.conf', for a host that only uses local service you would see:

```
passwd:     files
shadow:     files
group:      files
```

If you see anything else there, you need to check that service configuration, and probably copy it over.

Also you would probably also want to copy the users` files by copying the '/home' directory if it is not stored on a central shared storage server. '/var/spool' might also contain user configuration and data such as cron jobs and unopened mail messages.

On a typical CentOS system (6 and up), you would probably see this in '/etc/nsswitch.conf':

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
```

This is because most external directory access had been delegated to sssd in CentOS. Its configuration can be found in the '/etc/sssd' directory.

Answer (score 1):

if nsswitch on the target host is configured to look at those files, yes, that should be sufficient.  Although you probably want to copy /etc/shadow as well if you want the passwords to be the same.

The "Name Service Switch" configuration file tells the system where to look for users and user related data.  You can find more information using "man 5 nsswitch.conf" or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html.

If you want to keep your user information in sync you might consider using NIS (NIS+ if security is important) or LDAP.

Comment: could you describe nsswitch, I don't see any mention of /etc/passwd or /etc/group in nsswitch.conf